# Usage of Nächster

Tags: grammar, english-to-german

I am quite new to german. I am confused with the ending of the word 'Nächster'.

Nächstes Jahr

Nächsten Monat

Nächste Woche

How does it work? I think it depends on the Declension. But somewhere I read Nächsten Fenster. Shouldn't it be Nächstes Fenster?

Comment: Your question is unfortunately a bit too broad for this site. For starters, have a look at this site: http://deutsch-als-fremdsprache-grammatik.de/DaF/Artikel/DaF-Artikel.html (Answers to your question are in green there)

Comment: @CarstenS the question you linked is not the same as this. This question is not about the same word with different declinations. This is about the declination according to the genus of the noun. But it is still too broad...

Answer (score 1):

Which *Artikel* you use depends on the genus of the corresponding word.

> **Das** Jahr *(neutral)*
>
> **Der** Monat *(masculin)*
>
> **Die** Woche *(feminin)*

But "*nächsten* Fenster" can also be correct. You need to set it in a context of a sentence. Just the two words are not correct; that would indeed be "*Das* nächste Fenster".

But if you build the following sentence the usage of "nächsten" is correct:

> Es hängt am nächsten Fenster.

Here you got the combination of the genus and the *casus* of the object (*Fenster* in this sentence). Fenster is the dative obejct. You can be sure about that by simply asking "An w**em** oder **was** hängt es?" - "Am/An dem Fenster".